Ag grid custom text editor with dropdown list
Ag grid currently does not support a cell editor that has capability to text edit and have a drop down list.
I would like to have a cell editor that user can edit by text AND have a drop down list to choose from as they type where user does not have choose from the drop down list.
I have looked at several solutions

agRichSelectCellEditor from ag grid
https://github.com/avallete/ag-grid-autocomplete-editor

But these solutions don't allow the user to store values they typed into the cell. Has anyone tried to implement such custom cell editor for ag grid?

We implemented our own solution for our project at https://tanstack.com/. It looks and works OK, maybe you should take a closer look at this library

@guriev you just advertised your own project without targeting the exact solution for the question asked.

@chelseama But these solutions don't allow the user to store values they typed into the cell what did you exactly mean by store values? are you sure you checked how ag-grid-autocomplete-editor works?

@diego-d Why advertised? I meant that I USED tanstask and it seemed like a good solution with many possibilities.

https://tanstack.com/table/latest/docs/framework/react/examples/editable-data

@DiegoD what I mean is to be able to edit the cell by typing not only by selecting from dropdown list. ag-grid-autocomplete-editor doesn't seem to allow that

Yes, I have tried and made the same thing.
hint:
there are 2 type of data, root level data, node's own data.
you need to save your data manually and during preselected, you need to select your  dropdown value so it can be shown as selected
